# Can't return/render html from a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm pretty new with angular's directives and trying to achieve a simple directive that renders dynamic html.
Consider the following html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</body>
```

What i would like to achieve is a result of

```
<span>My HTML<span>
```

Style:

```
span {
  color:blue;
}
```

My directive:

```
myApp.directive("myDirective", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      text: "="
    },
    template: '{{test}}',
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.test  = "<span>My HTML<span>";
    }
  }
}]);
```

All my attempts failed, here's my [codepen example](http://codepen.io/OTomer/pen/gPrEeM), hope you could help me with that because it feels like im missing something.
Btw, i believe the reason it's because it is HTML, so i tried to use $sce, but still no success with that.

Edited: I added css style for span tag, so once it will work the color of the text should be blue.

Comment: I've modified it slightly - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGNamw

Comment: You have added `replace:true` property which requires template must have a root element. So move your `span` element to `template: '<span>{{test}}</span>',`

Comment: i don't want to move the span from the link method, consider it as a dynamic code that generates html

Comment: Thee issue @rahilwazir mentioned is evident from the error message you get in the console (always, always, check the console for errors): https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt

Comment: @Popokoko You still need the template to have at least one root element.

Comment: @Popokoko Then don't move the `span`, either declare a root element or remove `replace:true` altogether

Comment: @FrailWords your solution doesn't work, consider an attempt to apply css for ur span result and it won't work because it is rendered as text and not html

Comment: @rahilwazir could you please adjust the code to show your solution? i am guessing i don't really understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @Popokoko thanks for the new insight, i didn't know/realize that.

Comment: I find the idea of directives to b able to generate dynamic html, weird im unable to achieve this result

Comment: @Popokoko Have a look http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGNagP I added a root `div` element with `ng-bind-html` directive which compiles raw string to html instead, also note I have used the `$sce.trustAsHtml` method to allow safe html.

Comment: @rahilwazir perfect! this is exactly what i tried to achieve :)
I'll be glad to approve your answer as the solution for my problem.
Could you post it in a separate post here and i'll accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you would not bind variables to the scope of the directive, but to the scope of your controller. Try to avoid $scope as much as possible, as this is best practice.

Your index.html would look like:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</body>
```

Your controller:

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.test = "Test";
});
```

And finally, your directive:

```
myApp.directive("myDirective", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<span>{{vm.test}}</span>',
    replace: true,
    controller: "myCtrl",
    controllerAs: "vm"
  }
}]);
```

Notice, that your variable "test" is bound to the controller directly. The controller is referenced by "controller" and "controllerAs" in your directive.

Let me know, if that helps you.

EDIT:
If you want to assign the variable value inside the link method you can try:

```
myApp.directive("myDirective", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      text: "@"
    },
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<span ng-bind="text"></span>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.text = "<span>...</span>";
    }
  }
}]);
```

A few things:

- scope.text: "=" only applies, if you get the text prop from the html element
- use "@" instead, if you assign it inside the directive
- variables defined inside scope are referenced by the variable name only, when inside the template
- directives always need a single root element in the template
- you can use ng-bind or ng-bind-html (with your $sceProvider) to bind your dynamic html to that root element

Comment: Thank you @Rico but as long as u put the "<span/>" html directly into the template attribute, i find it as a solution to some other problem.
Consider the fact span tag could be multiple tags or a dynamic html that is generated inside the link method, i couldn't explicitly write it in the template attribute, this is why i wrote: 'template: "{{test}}"'

Comment: @Popokoko For the bindings you can then use: `bindToController`

Comment: Please check my edit to see, if that fits your needs

Comment: Well after editing your solution does look good, also, u did mention few points that are making more sense to me now regarding the usage of directives
Many thank mate :)